# How do I make a WPF popup draggable using a thumb?

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, draggable

I've searched long and hard to find an example of this on the net.  I've seen the alternative methods for this but I want to specifically use a thumb.  In trying to hash out a solution I've been unable to get the functionality right/working as I'm fairly new to WPF.  I'd be grateful if someone could give an example of how you may implement the above.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

A `Popup` doesn't give you an obvious way to move it; you can only place it relative to its placement target.  However it does give you and additional offset relative to the placement target and that's enough to move it anywhere.

Here's a working markup-only solution that demonstrates a draggable `Popup` using a `Thumb` using [Markup Programming](http://markupprogramming.codeplex.com/).  There is a text box that has a popup that pops up when the text box receives the keyboard focus.  The popup has some text and a thumb.

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:p="http://markupprogramming.codeplex.com/markup/programming"
    Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" Width="200" Height="20"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Popup Name="popup" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=textBox1}"
               IsOpen="{Binding IsKeyboardFocused, ElementName=textBox1, Mode=OneWay}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Background="White" Text="Sample Popup content."/>
                <Thumb Name="thumb" Width="20" Height="20"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <p:Attached.Operations>
                <p:ScriptHandler Path="@FindElement('thumb').DragDelta">
                    @AssociatedObject.HorizontalOffset += @EventArgs.HorizontalChange;
                    @AssociatedObject.VerticalOffset += @EventArgs.VerticalChange;
                </p:ScriptHandler>
            </p:Attached.Operations>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Is it any way to use Markup Programming in .NET 3.5?